# Как добавить option в Angular?

Tags: angularstrap, angularjs

Как добавить новый option в уже существующий select list в разметке? Сейчас первый пункт option пустой

Comment: ng-options директива не подходит? Или вы не знаете, как пользоваться? Или я не понял вопроса. :(

Comment: ng-options работает, когда генерится весь список на ангуларе. А у меня список создан заведомо пхп в разметке

Comment: в таком случае лучше передать управление по созданию списка ангуляру, либо использовать javascript/jQuery для добавления в уже существующий список, но это уже менее красиво будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Постарайтесь использовать встроенные средства Angular для данной проблемы:`ng-options`

**HTML:**

```
$scope.options = [{key:"1", value: "value1"},{key:"2", value: "value2"},{key:"3", value: "value3"}];
```

**Angular:**

```
 <select ng-options="opt.key for opt in options "></select>
```

2. Если управление списком не возможно передать Angular можно попробовать написать `directive` :

```js
(function() {

  var app = angular.module("myapp", []);

  app.directive("drSelect", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      compile: function(element, attributes) {
        return {
          pre: function(scope, element, attributes, controller, transcludeFn) {
            var newDirective = angular.element('<option>123</option');
            element.append(newDirective);
          }
        }
      }
    };
  });

}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp">
  <select dr-select></select>
</div>
```

[Ссылка](http://plnkr.co/edit/wFlpcScdA4TZa70MmhAi?p=preview) на пример